# JSTL: PropertyNotFoundException in JSTL using EL

Tags: jsp, exception, jstl, el

When I try to use the property of an object in el expression in jsp, the PropertyNotFound exception is generated. Following is my code:

```
public class Pledges {
  private Integer amount;
  private String creward;
  // proper getter setter

.............................

 ArrayList<Pledges> pledges ;
 pledges = entry.getPledges();
 request.setAttribute("pledges", pledges);

............................

  <c:forEach items=" ${pledges}" var="pledge">
    <input type='radio' name='rewards' id='r1' value='Option 1' />
    <label for='r1'>${pledge.creward}
    </label> <br /> <br />
  </c:forEach>
```

The following exception is thrown in jsp pages:

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'creward' not found on type java.lang.String

Answer (score 1):

Your `items` is evaluated as `String`. And indeed, you've a space (a string character) in the front of the EL expression, which implicitly coerces the whole expression to `String`.

```
<c:forEach items=" ${pledges}" var="pledge">
```

Get rid of that space.

```
<c:forEach items="${pledges}" var="pledge">
```